# How to simplify $x^a(u+v)^b$ and $(x+y)^a(u+v)^b$ when $a, b$ are binary digits?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, boolean-algebra

Say $a, b \in \{0,1\}$ and everything else is, say, a real number (though I don't think it should matter). Consider the following two expressions

$$
(\mathrm{i})\,\, x^a(u+v)^b \qquad \qquad  (\mathrm{ii})\,\, (x+y)^a(u+v)^b
$$

Is there a way to simplify any of these expressions?

For example, we can see
\begin{align*}
x^a(u+v)^b = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $ab = 00$}\\
u+v & \text{if $ab = 01$}\\
x & \text{if $ab = 10$}\\
xu + xv & \text{if $ab = 11$}.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

I'd like to distribute the $x^a$ somehow. Same goes for (ii).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Find a linear function such that $f(0) = 1$ and $ f(1) = x$. Then, $f(a) = x^a$.

Comment: hmm...looks like $f(a) = a(x-1) +1$.

Comment: Yea, so $ x^a = a(x-1) + 1$ since $ a \in \{0, 1\}$, which turns an exponential function into a linear function, which I think counts as "simplification".